# I want to join 2 table where in result I want to fetch selected columns only

Tags: mysql

I want to join 2 table in which I want to fetch all columns of table 1 and 4 columns of table 2, where pid is common field in both table.

```
SELECT table1.*, 
table2.date, 
table2.ft1,
table2.to1,
table2.match1
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.poolid = table2.poolid
WHERE table1.poolid=‘2018011301’
```

Comment: whats your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.date, table2.ft1,table2.to1,table2.match1 from table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.poolid = table2.poolid WHERE table1.poolid=‘2018011301’
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it gives me same result. @sanjit Bhardwaj

Comment: i do not understand , the query is standard and working fine for me.

Comment: ok thanks, now i want to split this query response in 2 arrays than what should i do ? @sanjit Bhardwaj

Comment: it means you want first table output in array1 and table2 output in array2